# How to clear the selected row in richfaces Extendeddatatable?

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to delete data table values. My data tables have a lot of values. When I click to delete particular row in my data table then confirmation dialog box open. If click okay then call to bean and delete that values to database. If click cancel then not to call to bean. This is my functionality.

ex: My data table has 10 rows. When I select 1 row delete button clicked call to bean it delete the selected row and data table get updated has 9 rows, but the selection is moved to next row. How can I deselect the selection in the data table?